# How to loop through a dictionary nested in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a dictionary that is nested in a list. It looks like this:

```
person_0 = {
    'first_name' : 'joe',
    'last_name' : 'schmoe',
    'age' : '35',
    'city' : 'houston',
    }

person_1 = {
    'first_name' : 'angela',
    'last_name' : 'yee',
    'age' : '42',
    'city' : 'new york',
    }

person_2 = {
    'first_name' : 'erykah',
    'last_name' : 'badu',
    'age' : '50',
    'city' : 'dallas',
    }

people = [person_0, person_1, person_2]
```

I want an output like this but with simpler code:

```
print(person_0['first_name'] + " " + person_0['last_name'])
print(person_1['first_name'] + " " + person_1['last_name'])
print(person_2['first_name'] + " " + person_2['last_name'])
```

However, when I run this for loop:

```
for persons in people:
    for person_info in persons.keys():
        full_name = persons['first_name'] +" "+ persons['last_name']
        print(full_name)
```

I get this output:

```
joe schmoe
joe schmoe
joe schmoe
joe schmoe
angela yee
angela yee
angela yee
angela yee
erykah badu
erykah badu
erykah badu
erykah badu
```

I also tried this for loop:

```
people = [person_0, person_1, person_2]
#print(people)
for persons in people:
    for person, person_info in persons.items():
        full_name = person_info['first_name'] +" "+ person_info['last_name']
        print(full_name)
```

I receive a type error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers.

In fact when I use an integer with in the brackets it returns a slice of the text instead of returning the value of the matching key.
Any suggestions or help is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you add a second loop in your first attempt? Just remove it.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Don't use list comprehension as a loop replacement.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I'd say to never use a list comprehension to execute method that returns nothing, that's not made for it

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to loop twice, once is enough :

```
people = [{'first_name': 'joe', 'last_name': 'schmoe', 'age': '35', 'city': 'houston'},
          {'first_name': 'angela', 'last_name': 'yee', 'age': '42', 'city': 'new york'},
          {'first_name': 'erykah', 'last_name': 'badu', 'age': '50', 'city': 'dallas'}]

for person in people:
    print(person['first_name'], person['last_name'])
```